# Can we know which element in fields array got edited in React Hook Form "useFieldArray"

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form useFieldArray. I have prepopulated the initial data which I got from API. I have almost 20 objects in an array. how can I know only which object data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Check `formState.isDirty` to see if the user changed any of the input fields, or `formState.dirtyFields` to get the specific fields changed by the user.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate